# Modify php mail script to display a popup message and redirect to another page on the website

Tags: php

I have a form that when submitted sends an email using the inbuilt php `mail()` function.

How do I either:

1. Display a pop-up message to confirm the form was submitted, and the email sent.

*or*

2. Redirect to another page once complete

I would prefer option 1.

```
if($_POST) {   
    $name = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactName']));
    $email = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactEmail']));
    $subject = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactSubject']));
    $contact_message = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactMessage']));

    // Check Name
    if (strlen($name) < 2) {
        $error['name'] = "Please enter your name.";
    }
    // Check Email
    if (!preg_match('/^[a-z0-9&\'\.\-_\+]+@[a-z0-9\-]+\.([a-z0-9\-]+\.)*+[a-z]{2}/is', $email)) {
        $error['email'] = "Please enter a valid email address.";
    }
    // Check Message
    if (strlen($contact_message) < 15) {
        $error['message'] = "Please enter your message. It should have at least 15 characters.";
    }
    // Subject
    if ($subject == '') { $subject = "Contact Form Submission"; }


    // Set Message
    $message .= "Email from: " . $name . "<br />";
    $message .= "Email address: " . $email . "<br />";
    $message .= "Message: <br />";
    $message .= $contact_message;
    $message .= "<br /> ----- <br /> This email was sent from your site's contact form. <br />";

    // Set From: header
    $from =  $name . " <" . $email . ">";

    // Email Headers
    $headers = "From: " . $from . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ". $email . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";


    if (!$error) {
        ini_set("sendmail_from", $siteOwnersEmail); // for windows server
        $mail = mail($siteOwnersEmail, $subject, $message, $headers);
        if ($mail) { echo "ok. (Here pop up saying its submitted and redirects)"; }
        else { echo "Something went wrong. Please try again."; }
    } # end if - no validation error
    else {
        $response = (isset($error['name'])) ? $error['name'] . "<br /> \n" : null;
        $response .= (isset($error['email'])) ? $error['email'] . "<br /> \n" : null;
        $response .= (isset($error['message'])) ? $error['message'] . "<br />" : null;
        echo $response;
    } # end if - there was a validation error
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you submit the form, you start a new request so PHP can output any html/javascript you like; you could also just tell it to redirect to a new page.

So you can easily implement either option, for displaying a popup, all you need to do is output the relevant javascript.

## Option 1 - "Popup"

If you mean a simple alert dialog that pops up, then the javascript you would need to output is `alert('Email sent successfully')` - if you mean opening a new window then it would be `window.open('newpage.html')`

Either way this you would need to wrap the command in script tags:

```
echo "<script>alert('Email sent successfully');</script>";
```

This should be placed either in your `<head>` or `<body>` tags.

## Option 2 - Redirect

When you say redirect, I'm not sure if this is necessary, but it depends where you have placed your code. After sending the email you could choose to output completely different HTML, therefore making your new page. You would need to make sure that your email code happens before any output from your old page. e.g.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    //process form and send email
    $mail = mail($siteOwnersEmail, $subject, $message, $headers);
    if ($mail) { 
        include 'emailsent.php';
    }else{
        $include 'emailerror.php';
    }
}else{
    include 'form.php'
}
```

You could replace the includes with a series of echos or break out of php

```
if ($mail) { 
    ?><html>...</html><?php
}
```

if you really want to redirect you can use the header function to send the Location header:

```
header('Location: emailsent.html');
```

See php docs for this here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

If you do this you must make sure you do it before any output has started (echo/print etc.) - this also includes any content before your php e.g. `<html><?php` would cause errors like this:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /some/file.php:12) in /some/file.php on line 23

You can find more info on this here: [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Comment: I tried to place the header line under the mail function and also by replacing echo ok. But it did not work. any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a timer event. 
Set it for about 20 seconds.

Set the timer 
Echo your message sent
If timer =20

Header(Location
Then use an if statement to
[PHP timer](http://php.net/manual/en/event.addtimer.php)